# How to delete data as rowwise in gridview when the page load occur in asp.net c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, delete-row

I want to delete the data from the Grid and when I insert the new data it should be display in grid.This should happen when the page load occurs.I tried this code.

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Gv1.DeleteRow(6);
     }
```

Comment: what did you tried to achieve this ? try google first. Also post some code to let us know.

Comment: Try some basic asp.net tutorials. There are plenty out there that cover the basics such as this.

Answer (score 0):

After you do any modification on GridView you have to call the Update method to reflect the changes.